# How to i check if a blocks overlap with a block that is already placed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function

```
    def has_overlap(self, position: typing.Tuple[float, float], block: typing.Tuple[float, float], 
                    solution: typing.Dict[typing.Tuple[float, float], typing.Tuple[float, float]]):
        """
        Function that checks whether the block overlaps with other blocks in the solution 
        if it would be placed on the given position

        :param position: the (x,y) coordinate pair where the block is to be placed
        :param block: the block (width_block1, height_block1)
        :param solution: the current solution (dictionary mapping positions (x,y)->(block_width, block_height))

        Returns True if there is overlap between the block on position and the other blocks in the solution
        False otherwise
        """
```

For the def, i need to make a function to check if I place a block on the given position, will that block overlap with the block that already is place. I have searched on the internet, but didn't find a good solution or a goof explanation to solve this problem. I have find a formula/code that checks if 2 blocks overlap if it is placed at the same time, see beneath

```
You have two blocks like this:

blockA = {x1, y1, x2, y2}
blockB = {x3, y3, x4, y4}
And then, Do,

(blockA.x1 - blockB.x4) * (blockA.x2 - blockB.x3) = X
(blockA.y1 - blockB.y4) * (blockA.y2 - blockB.y3) = Y
if X < 0 and Y < 0, it's overlapped.
```

So at the moment i dont have the width or the height of the block for the block that already is placed, so my question is can someone help me further to solve this def?

Comment: `at the moment i dont have the width or the height of the block for the block that already is placed` You can find width of the first block using width = y2 - y1, right?

Comment: i only have the position coordinated of the block that is already placed

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).